# ECONNREFUSED al installar opensearch

Tags: networking, elasticsearch, connection, opensearch

Intento installar OpenSearch desde [la documentacion official](https://opensearch.org/downloads.html) pero tengo varios problemas y advertencias. Los Errores son de conexión a OpenSearch: OpenSearch Dashboards no puede conectarse a OpenSearch debido a un error de conexión (`ECONNREFUSED`). Esto podría deberse a un problema en la configuración.

- No pienso que es al hecho de que OpenSearch no esté en funcionamiento porque debe incializarse despues de ser instalado.
- No pienso que es a causa de la RAM porque es indicado Memory: 4 GB
- No pienso que es un problema en la configuración porque el docker-compose.yaml proviene de [la documentacion official](https://opensearch.org/downloads.html).

¿Auriez tienes una idea? El o ella que trae la razón recibe un reconocimiento eterno

Aqui estan las adverencias, si pueden ser la razon:

- Advertencia sobre herramienta obsoleta: Se muestra una advertencia informando que una herramienta se va a descontinuar en futuras versiones de OpenSearch. Se proporciona un enlace para obtener más información.
- Advertencia sobre el uso en sistemas públicos: Se advierte que el instalador de seguridad no debe utilizarse en sistemas públicos o en producción.
- Advertencia de seguridad: Se advierte sobre el uso de un método obsoleto en java.lang.System. Se sugiere informar sobre este problema a los responsables de OpenSearch, ya que el método obsoleto se eliminará en futuras versiones.
- Advertencias de permisos inseguros de directorios: Se emiten advertencias sobre permisos inseguros en un directorio en la configuración de OpenSearch. Esto podría representar un riesgo de seguqaridad.

Pero dudo.

```
(base) remplacement@remplacements-MacBook-Pro Downloads % docker-compose up
[+] Running 3/0
 ✔ Container opensearch-dashboards  C...                                   0.0s 
 ✔ Container opensearch-node2       Create...                              0.0s 
 ✔ Container opensearch-node1       Create...                              0.0s 
Attaching to opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-node1, opensearch-node2
opensearch-node1       | Enabling execution of install_demo_configuration.sh for OpenSearch Security Plugin
opensearch-node2       | Enabling execution of install_demo_configuration.sh for OpenSearch Security Plugin
opensearch-node1       | **************************************************************************
opensearch-node1       | ** This tool will be deprecated in the next major release of OpenSearch **
opensearch-node1       | ** https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/issues/1755           **
opensearch-node1       | **************************************************************************
opensearch-node2       | **************************************************************************
opensearch-node2       | ** This tool will be deprecated in the next major release of OpenSearch **
opensearch-node2       | ** https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/issues/1755           **
opensearch-node2       | **************************************************************************
opensearch-node1       | OpenSearch Security Demo Installer
opensearch-node1       |  ** Warning: Do not use on production or public reachable systems **
opensearch-node2       | OpenSearch Security Demo Installer
opensearch-node2       |  ** Warning: Do not use on production or public reachable systems **
opensearch-node2       | Basedir: /usr/share/opensearch
opensearch-node1       | Basedir: /usr/share/opensearch
opensearch-node1       | OpenSearch install type: rpm/deb on Amazon Linux release 2023 (Amazon Linux)
opensearch-node1       | OpenSearch config dir: /usr/share/opensearch/config
opensearch-node1       | OpenSearch config file: /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml
opensearch-node1       | OpenSearch bin dir: /usr/share/opensearch/bin
opensearch-node1       | OpenSearch plugins dir: /usr/share/opensearch/plugins
opensearch-node1       | OpenSearch lib dir: /usr/share/opensearch/lib
opensearch-node1       | Detected OpenSearch Version: x-content-2.10.0
opensearch-node1       | Detected OpenSearch Security Version: 2.10.0.0
opensearch-node2       | OpenSearch install type: rpm/deb on Amazon Linux release 2023 (Amazon Linux)
opensearch-node2       | OpenSearch config dir: /usr/share/opensearch/config
opensearch-node2       | OpenSearch config file: /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml
opensearch-node2       | OpenSearch bin dir: /usr/share/opensearch/bin
opensearch-node2       | OpenSearch plugins dir: /usr/share/opensearch/plugins
opensearch-node2       | OpenSearch lib dir: /usr/share/opensearch/lib
opensearch-node2       | Detected OpenSearch Version: x-content-2.10.0
opensearch-node2       | Detected OpenSearch Security Version: 2.10.0.0
opensearch-node1       | /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml seems to be already configured for Security. Quit.
opensearch-node2       | /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml seems to be already configured for Security. Quit.
opensearch-node2       | Enabling OpenSearch Security Plugin
opensearch-node1       | Enabling OpenSearch Security Plugin
opensearch-node2       | Enabling execution of OPENSEARCH_HOME/bin/opensearch-performance-analyzer/performance-analyzer-agent-cli for OpenSearch Performance Analyzer Plugin
opensearch-node1       | Enabling execution of OPENSEARCH_HOME/bin/opensearch-performance-analyzer/performance-analyzer-agent-cli for OpenSearch Performance Analyzer Plugin
opensearch-node2       | WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
opensearch-node2       | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.10.0.jar)
opensearch-node2       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch
opensearch-node2       | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.10.0.jar)
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.Security (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.10.0.jar)
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.opensearch.bootstrap.Security
opensearch-node1       | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
opensearch-node2       | WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
opensearch-node2       | WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.Security (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.10.0.jar)
    ...
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doInternalExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:309) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:220) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:118) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:218) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.indexmanagement.rollup.actionfilter.FieldCapsFilter.apply(FieldCapsFilter.kt:118) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.indexmanagement.controlcenter.notification.filter.IndexOperationActionFilter.apply(IndexOperationActionFilter.kt:39) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.filter.SecurityFilter.apply0(SecurityFilter.java:290) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.filter.SecurityFilter.apply(SecurityFilter.java:165) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.action.PerformanceAnalyzerActionFilter.apply(PerformanceAnalyzerActionFilter.java:78) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:188) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportSingleItemBulkWriteAction.doExecute(TransportSingleItemBulkWriteAction.java:73) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportSingleItemBulkWriteAction.doExecute(TransportSingleItemBulkWriteAction.java:53) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:218) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.indexmanagement.rollup.actionfilter.FieldCapsFilter.apply(FieldCapsFilter.kt:118) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.indexmanagement.controlcenter.notification.filter.IndexOperationActionFilter.apply(IndexOperationActionFilter.kt:39) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.filter.SecurityFilter.apply0(SecurityFilter.java:290) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.filter.SecurityFilter.apply(SecurityFilter.java:165) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.action.PerformanceAnalyzerActionFilter.apply(PerformanceAnalyzerActionFilter.java:78) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:188) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:107) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:110) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:97) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:476) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:463) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:487) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.support.ConfigHelper.lambda$uploadFile$0(ConfigHelper.java:97) ~[opensearch-security-2.10.0.0.jar:2.10.0.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.support.ConfigHelper.uploadFile(ConfigHelper.java:86) ~[opensearch-security-2.10.0.0.jar:2.10.0.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.support.ConfigHelper.uploadFile(ConfigHelper.java:65) ~[opensearch-security-2.10.0.0.jar:2.10.0.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at org.opensearch.security.configuration.ConfigurationRepository.lambda$new$0(ConfigurationRepository.java:146) [opensearch-security-2.10.0.0.jar:2.10.0.0]
opensearch-node2       |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,679][INFO ][o.o.a.u.d.DestinationMigrationCoordinator] [opensearch-node1] Detected cluster change event for destination migration
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,677][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node2] No data for internalusers while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,687][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node2] No data for actiongroups while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,688][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node2] No data for config while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,689][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node2] No data for roles while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,690][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node2] No data for rolesmapping while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,690][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node2] No data for tenants while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,709][INFO ][o.o.a.u.d.DestinationMigrationCoordinator] [opensearch-node2] Detected cluster change event for destination migration
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,767][ERROR][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationRepository] [opensearch-node1] Cannot apply default config (this is maybe not an error!)
opensearch-node1       | org.opensearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: index [.opendistro_security] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.indicesBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:243) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.TransportAutoPutMappingAction.checkBlock(TransportAutoPutMappingAction.java:106) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.TransportAutoPutMappingAction.checkBlock(TransportAutoPutMappingAction.java:58) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.clustermanager.TransportClusterManagerNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.doStart(TransportClusterManagerNodeAction.java:237) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.clustermanager.TransportClusterManagerNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.tryAction(TransportClusterManagerNodeAction.java:206) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.RetryableAction$1.doRun(RetryableAction.java:137) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:52) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.OpenSearchExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(OpenSearchExecutors.java:343) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.RetryableAction.run(RetryableAction.java:115) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.clustermanager.TransportClusterManagerNodeAction.doExecute(TransportClusterManagerNodeAction.java:167) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.TransportAutoPutMappingAction.doExecute(TransportAutoPutMappingAction.java:100) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.TransportAutoPutMappingAction.doExecute(TransportAutoPutMappingAction.java:58) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:218) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.indexmanagement.rollup.actionfilter.FieldCapsFilter.apply(FieldCapsFilter.kt:118) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.indexmanagement.controlcenter.notification.filter.IndexOperationActionFilter.apply(IndexOperationActionFilter.kt:39) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.security.filter.SecurityFilter.apply0(SecurityFilter.java:290) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.security.filter.SecurityFilter.apply(SecurityFilter.java:165) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.performanceanalyzer.action.PerformanceAnalyzerActionFilter.apply(PerformanceAnalyzerActionFilter.java:78) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:216) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:188) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:107) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:110) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:97) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:476) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1537) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.cluster.action.index.MappingUpdatedAction.sendUpdateMapping(MappingUpdatedAction.java:161) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.cluster.action.index.MappingUpdatedAction.updateMappingOnClusterManager(MappingUpdatedAction.java:126) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.lambda$dispatchedShardOperationOnPrimary$1(TransportShardBulkAction.java:414) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeBulkItemRequest(TransportShardBulkAction.java:644) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction$2.doRun(TransportShardBulkAction.java:466) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:908) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:52) ~[opensearch-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
opensearch-node1       |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node1       |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
opensearch-node1       |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,811][INFO ][o.o.a.u.d.DestinationMigrationCoordinator] [opensearch-node1] Detected cluster change event for destination migration
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,818][INFO ][o.o.a.u.d.DestinationMigrationCoordinator] [opensearch-node2] Detected cluster change event for destination migration
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,831][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node1] No data for internalusers while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,832][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node1] No data for actiongroups while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,832][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node1] No data for config while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,833][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node1] No data for roles while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,833][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node1] No data for rolesmapping while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:56,833][WARN ][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-node1] No data for tenants while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT]  (index=.opendistro_security)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:57,301][INFO ][o.o.c.r.a.AllocationService] [opensearch-node2] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.opensearch-sap-log-types-config][0]]]).
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:57,396][INFO ][o.o.a.u.d.DestinationMigrationCoordinator] [opensearch-node1] Detected cluster change event for destination migration
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:57,401][INFO ][o.o.a.u.d.DestinationMigrationCoordinator] [opensearch-node2] Detected cluster change event for destination migration
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:57,636][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node2] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:57,736][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node1] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:18:57,743][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node2] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:18:57,744][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node1] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-10-11T10:18:57Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ResponseError]: Response Error"}
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:19:00,145][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node2] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:19:00,159][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node1] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:19:00,162][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node2] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:19:00,165][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node1] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-10-11T10:19:00Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ResponseError]: Response Error"}
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:19:02,658][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node2] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:19:02,676][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node1] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node2       | [2023-10-11T10:19:02,681][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node2] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-node1       | [2023-10-11T10:19:02,683][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-node1] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-10-11T10:19:02Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ResponseError]: Response Error"}
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the OpenSearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-node2:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch-node2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1:9200","https://opensearch-node2:9200"]'
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
```